# bootstrap accordion

Tags: angularjs

Есть код:

```
    <uib-accordion-group ng-repeat="li in list">
    <uib-accordion-heading>
        <a ng-click="active(li.name)" href="{{li.link}}"><i class="fa" ng-class="li.icon"></i> {{li.name}}<i class="pull-right fa fa-angle-right" ng-show="li.submenu.length"></i></a>
    </uib-accordion-heading>

                   <div>
            <ul class="childrenul">
                <li ng-repeat="subitem in li.submenu">{{subitem}}</li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </uib-accordion-group>
</uib-accordion>
```

Берется он из массива. Но суть в другом он создает меню аккордеон, но мне нужны не все пункты аккордионом, а только лишь те у которых есть дочерние итемы, а он преобразует все. как это можно сделать?

Comment: добавьте массив по которому строится

Comment: @Grundy, $scope.list = [{
                name:'Панель',
                icon:'fa-tachometer',
                submenu:[],
                link: "#"
            },
            {
                name:'Редактор',
                icon:'fa-pencil-square-o',
                submenu:[],
                link: "#"
            },
         
            {
                name:'Прочее',
                icon:'fa-pie-chart',
                submenu:['Лиды','Цели','Статистика'],
                link: "#"
            }

Comment: То есть на выходе нужен только раздел "Прочее"?

Comment: @mix, то есть на выходе?

Comment: Из массива нужно выбросить все свойства с пустым `submenu`?

Comment: @mix, нет, нужно превращение в аккордион только тех пунктов что имеют итемы